# Comparison of effect sizes $\phi$, $r_{pb}$, $r_{rb}$, $G$, $r$

Tags: correlation, effect-size

Given 5 significant correlation coefficients:

- A phi correlation coefficient $\phi$
- A point-biserial correlation coefficient $r_{pb}$
- A rank-biserial correlation coeffcient $r_{rb}$
- A Goodman & Kruskal Gamma correlation coefficient $G$
- A Pearson product moment correlation coefficient $r$

All of them lie in $\left[-1,1\right]$. Accordingly, it is tempting to compare them purely on their numerical value.
But is this safe and meaningful? Can I compare them with each other with the goal to establish an "order of effect size/strength"?

For example:

- Test 1: $\phi = 0.5$
- Test 2: $G = 0.6$

Can I state that the effect in Test 2 is stronger than the effect in Test 1?

Comment: Why did you decide not to use the same coefficient for each situation?

Comment: It's more a kind of theoretical question towards data with different scales. $\phi$ for nominal/nominal data, $r_{pb}$ for nominal/continuous data, $r_{rb}$ for nominal/ordinal data, $G$ for ordinal/ordinal data, $r$ for continuous/continuous data.

Comment: To corroborate @enfi, you use a specific type of correlation because of data assumptions. For example, you would use a Spearman rank correlation statistic if the assumptions for Pearson correlation statistic were violated severely. Statistical software (e.g. SPSS, SAS) often provide guidelines as to when a method should be used. Example: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/point-biserial-correlation-using-spss-statistics.php

Comment: Given the notion that some correlation coefficients may not be appropriate for certain data types, it may be unadvisable to compare any correlation statistic with any other. Some are comparable though, such as Pearson and Spearman; however, Pearson and Point-Biserial may not be safely comparable.

Comment: To correct my last comment, I found this on Wikipedia (no citation though): "The point-biserial correlation is mathematically equivalent to the Pearson (product moment) correlation, that is, if we have one continuously measured variable X and a dichotomous variable Y, rXY = rpb. This can be shown by assigning two distinct numerical values to the dichotomous variable." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient